# Laravel 4 - set image with jquery

Tags: jquery, image, laravel-4, src

I have a div where I show all the images I have in my server (I've saved the url and some information about every photo in my DB). This is my 'div':

```
<div class="row myImages" id="imagenesSubidas">
@foreach($imagen as $i)
@if(!file_exists('images/'.$i->ruta))
<div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6 thumb">
    <a href="" class="seleccionarImagen" id="{{ $i->id }}" data="{{ $i->ruta.$i->nombre }}">        
        {{ HTML::image($i->ruta.'/'.$i->nombre, '', array( 'width' => '100%', 'class' => 'img-responsive' )) }}     
    </a>
</div>
@endif
@endforeach
</div>
```

There is another div where I have an empty `HTML::image`. I would fill it with the image clicked in the DIV before. The 'HTML::image' I want to fill is:

```
{{ HTML::image('/images/IMG_0004.jpg', '', array( 'width' => 200, 'id' => 'id_imagen_1', 'class' => 'show_imagen1' )) }}
```

And I'm trying it with jQuery. This is my code:

```
$('.seleccionarImagen').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var ruta = $(this).attr('data');
        $("#id_imagen_1").attr('src', ruta); // I try to load the image with that
     });
```

My `var ruta` returns something like '/images/IMG_0010.jpg', but when I try to load it into my `HTML::image` I have not any response. Probably I'm doing it in a wrong way... Any idea how could I get it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
<a href="" class="seleccionarImagen" id="{{ $i->id }}" data="{{ $i->ruta.$i->nombre }}">
```

To:

```
<a href="" class="seleccionarImagen" id="{{ $i->id }}" data-ruta="{{ $i->ruta . '/' . $i->nombre }}">
```

And then change:

```
var ruta = $(this).attr('data');
```

To:

```
var ruta = $(this).data('ruta');
```

**UPDATE**

With the URL of the page being:

```
 http://localhost/webs/lara4/edu1/public/actividads/create
```

and if your `images` folder is in `public`, then `/images/IMG_0010.jpg` is trying to load from the wrong location:

```
http://localhost/images/IMG_0010.jpg
```

**You can define a virtual host for your app so that the `public` folder is the web root for the app and the images url would be correct.**

**A quick work-around would be to have:
`<base href="/webs/lara4/edu1/public/" />` somewhere in the head of your page or layout, if you have one, and remove the leading slash in the URLs of you images.**

Comment: My original code was something like yours. But when I try it, my `var ruta` returns me something like '/images//IMG_0010.jpg'. So, to avoid the second slash I changed my code. :S

Comment: Can you check the console (dev tools) and see if there's an error with regards to the URL?

Comment: My console doesn't say anything... Everything seems to be ok :(

Comment: Since this appears to be a client-side issue, can you create a jsfiddle by extracting sample html from your browser?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know how can I paste there my code... I'm looking for images I have in my server... If I do the same with liks (images on the internet) it works properly!

Comment: Interesting! Sounds like you have a `path` issue :(. What does your route (for the page in question) look like? Can you give the output of `console.log( ruta )` in the click event handler.

Comment: I have it in local, so my route is `http://localhost/webs/lara4/edu1/public/actividads/create`. And my images are saved in my `public` folder (in a folder called 'images')

Comment: Quite likely, you're trying to load the images from `http://localhost/images/....` which of course is the wrong location. What's the output of `console.log( ruta )`?

Comment: `What's the output of console.log( ruta )` sorry... I don't know what you mean... but, actually, if I paste manually the route I get with my jQuery ('/images/IMG_0010.jpg') in the HTML::image, it works good. Because of that I thought the problem was the way I try to send the route of the image by js

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60468/discussion-between-user3558931-and-javizu).

Comment: Thank you very much!! I've defined a virtual host and it works good now! ;)